# Как изменить права доступа к таблице с Editor до Viewer?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, права, доступ

Вот скрипт в таблице, который запускает редактор:

```
function ed2view() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var eds = ss.getEditors();
  var ed = eds[1];
  ss.removeEditor(ed);
  ss.addViewer(ed);
}
```

Не работает, т.к., видимо, к моменту addViewer() права уже отозваны.

Если просто addViewer(), без предварительного removeEditor(), тоже не работает: [If the user was already on the list of editors, this method has no effect](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addvieweremailaddress).

С другой стороны, через интерфейс таблицы редактор может понизить свои права доступа до Viewer.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как корректно понизить права доступа.

**UPD** 
Решение найдено, спасибо, @oshilaer. Возникавшая первоначально ошибка "ReferenceError: Объект "Drive" не определен" была вызвана тем, что не был включен Drive API: Редактор скриптов: Ресурсы/Дополнительные функции и в [консоли Google API](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

Comment: Этот код работает. У вас ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: @oshliaer код работает при запуске редактором? Мне нужно именно это.

Comment: @oshliaer вот [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A4SyOjLGfW93OKNGmyo-kG703Lr_V5xP9ZzjQF2edIY/edit)  Может, вы сделаете запрос? Я дам вам право на редактирование. Исправите скрипт так, как он, по-вашему, должен сработать, и проверим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная задача: сделать даунгрейд прав редактора самому себе.

Не надо манипулировать пользователями и доступом через файл Таблицы. Это опосредованные методы, которые реализуются только благодаря общему интерфейсу типа файл Диска.

Если использовать Advanced Drive Service, то все работает как часы

```
function run() {
  driveChangeMeRole_(FILE_ID, EMAIL);
}

/**
 * Downgrade you in the rights from the editor to the viewer
 * @param {string} fileId The file id
 * @param {string} email You can pass your email and downgrade youself
 * @returns {void}
 */
function driveChangeMeRole_(fileId, email) {
  var permissionId = Drive.Permissions.getIdForEmail(email);
  var resource = Drive.newPermission();
  resource.role = 'reader';
  /* You can stay as a commenter
  resource.additionalRoles = ['commenter']; */
  Drive.Permissions.update(resource, fileId, permissionId.id);
}
```

Редактор передает свой email и изменяет свои права на читателя или комментатора.

[Сниппет](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/driveapp_change_owner_in_folder)

Comment: @oshilaer Спасибо, это отличная мысль - "Не надо манипулировать пользователями и доступом через файл Таблицы... использовать Advanced Drive Service"!
Но **[код](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fWQuySdI5kqSIocb_UvtC86nWq0l-WrGVJKf_VtigOU/edit?usp=sharing)** выдаёт ошибку "ReferenceError: Объект "Drive" не определен. (строка 18, файл ed2view)".